# Which analysis method to use for mixed data types

Tags: cluster-analysis

I am trying to cluster a dataset that contains two variables:

One categorical variable that has 800 different levels of id and one continuous variable which measures the performance.

I know that K-means would not work due to the categorical one.

Should I use K-modes?

Any suggestion would be of big help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't pick a method by the data types.

Pick a method because of the problem it solves, or it may be solving a very different problem than yours.

If you have an id column, you pretty much always must not use it. So you then only have a single continuous variable. It may be more appropriate to use kernel density estimation rather than any clustering. You can use low density areas to split the data based on the KDE, too.